# Python XML parinsg is seeing unexpected tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML which is including following code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ops:OPS xmlns:ops="http://www.si2.org/schemas/OPS"
         opsVersion="OPS_1.1">
    <ops:RulesSection>
        [...some stuff..]
    </ops:RulesSection>
</ops:OPS>
```

When I'm parsing this file and checking Elements value I'm expecting to find an element called "ops:RulesSection"

```
from xml.etree                  import ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree      import ElementTree, Elem
tree = ET.parse(OPSDRMFile)
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    print("!!!",elem)
```

However I am getting following results

```
!!! <Element '{http://www.si2.org/schemas/OPS}RulesSection' at 0x2b557da50f98>
```

it seems that "ops:" tag has been replaced by its value from the beginning of the file... can someone explain if this is expected behavior? Is there a way to NOT expand such parameter?

(as of now if I want to perform further parsing I need to transfrom "ops:NewTagToFind" as "{http://www.si2.org/schemas/OPS}NewTagToFind" when I using "findall" command.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What you see is expected. The document uses a namespace, See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Thank you mzjn, I had this doc opened but stopped reading on previous chapter... Using ns_dict in order to shorten name as explained in example is also working well. :)